# Making an array that represents an integer array's indices

Tags: c

We've been asked to make a function that returns an integer pointer and takes the parameters

```
int *func(int *list,int size)
```

I want to create an integer array whose entries describe the position the entries in the original array would have when that array were sorted, but without sorting the original array,this should be done inside the function
and then return a pointer to entries array to the main function.
Ex:

**Main array**

```
3,17,9,2,11,26,5
```

**The returned array is**:

```
1,5,3,0,4,6,2
```

I'm thinking about sorting the main array after copying it into another array ! so the main order is not lost and then compare them together to fill the desired array of indices ,i think this is a bit long any other ideas ?

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking. "the function job is to make an integer array inside of the function body and return that array's initial address to main" sounds like implementing a bug on purpose, or did you intend to use dynamic allocation? Can you post the code of the function? Also I don't understand how "this array's elements must be the indices of the main array" corresponds to the data in your examples. It rather seems like the function gives the indices the numbers would have in a sorted array. This doesn't make any sense...

Comment: It isn't entirely clear to me what algorithm is used to determine the returned array from the main array. You should consider improving your question to obtain an answer.

Comment: As far as I unserstand you want to create an integer array whose entries describe the position the entries in the original array would have when that array were sorted, but without sorting the original array, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, but I can't help feeling there is an easier way.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int value;
    int index;
    int index2;
} sorter;

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return ((sorter*)a)->value - ((sorter*)b)->value;
}

int cmp2(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return ((sorter*)a)->index - ((sorter*)b)->index;
}

int *func(int *list, int size) {
    int i, *iarray;
    sorter *sarray = malloc(size * sizeof(sorter));
    if (sarray == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        sarray[i].index = i;                    // original position
        sarray[i].value = list[i];              // element value  
    }
    qsort (sarray, size, sizeof(sorter), cmp);  // sort by value
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)                      
        sarray[i].index2 = i;                   // sorted position
    qsort (sarray, size, sizeof(sorter), cmp2); // sort by original position
    iarray = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if (iarray == NULL) {
        free (sarray);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        iarray[i] = sarray[i].index2;           // position when sorted
    free (sarray);
    return iarray;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, size, *sorted, list[] = {3,17,9,2,11,26,5};
    size = sizeof(list)/sizeof(int);
    sorted = func(list, size);
    if (sorted == NULL)
        printf("Error in func\n");
    else {
        for (i=0; i<size; i++)
            printf("%d, ", sorted[i]);
        printf("\n");
        free(sorted);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
1, 5, 3, 0, 4, 6, 2,
```

Answer (score 1):

Your task involves sorting two arrays (value and position) simultaneously. To do that, you could:

- create an auxiliary array where you re-organise the array to keep value and position next to each other, so that you can use `qsort` on it;
- use the (inconveniently) non-standard `qsort_r`, which allows you to pas extra information to the sorting routine via a `void *`  ointer or
- roll your own sorting algorithm that keeps both array synchronised.

The first approach is the most usual and portable approach. The standard sorting function `qsort` can work on arrays, where the array elements can have any size. So: create an auxiliary array of (value, position) pairs, sort that by position and the fill the result array, which you must allocate on the heap:

```
struct pair {
    int val;
    int pos;
};

int paircmp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const struct pair *a = pa;
    const struct pair *b = pb;

    return (a->val > b->val) - (a->val < b->val);
}

int *func(int array[], int n)
{
    struct pair pair[n];
    int *result;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pair[i].val = array[i];
        pair[i].pos = i;
    }

    qsort(pair, n, sizeof(*pair), paircmp);

    result = malloc(n * sizeof(*result));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result[pair[i].pos] = i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here, `paircmp` is a comparison callback function for `qsort`.

The `[qsort_r][qsort_r]` approach is nice and clean, but the `qsort_r` function is a GNU extension that isn't portable. It still requires an auxiliary array. (There wouldn't even be any need for that if your array were an array of sorted indices.)

The steps are roghly the same as before: Create an auxiliary array of indices, sort that so that the array entries at these indices are sorted, and then create your result array:

```
int indexcmp(const void *pa, const void *pb, void *data)
{
    const int *a = pa;
    const int *b = pb;
    const int *array = data;

    return (array[*a] > array[*b]) - (array[*a] < array[*b]);
}

int *func2(int array[], int n)
{
    int *result = malloc(n * sizeof(*result));
    int pos[n];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) pos[i] = i;

    qsort_r(pos, n, sizeof(*pos), indexcmp, array);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) result[pos[i]] = i;

    return result;
}
```

The comparison function `indexcmp` takes an additional argument.

The third option, rolling your own sorting function, ist the most fun, but I'll leave that to you.